Adding leading zeros to data columns when loading from CSV files using pandas
I have a script to load and combine time-series data from two .csv files that have the same base filename (specified as a path using Pathlib), but different suffixes. Given that the importing of the data from the .csv files is working correctly, I include here a minimal working example with data provided using StringIO:
import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def load_data():
    headers_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c']  # Headers for first file. May have more entries than columns in file
    headers_1 = ['d', 'e']       # Headers for second file.

    data_0 = pd.read_csv(
        StringIO(
          """
            0 1 2
            3 4 5
            6 7 8
          """
          )
        , header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    data_0.columns = headers_0[0:data_0.shape[1]]

    data_1 = pd.read_csv(
        StringIO(
          """
            A B
            C D
          """
          )
        , header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    data_1.columns = headers_1[0:data_1.shape[1]]

    data = data_0.join(data_1)
    data.fillna(0, inplace=True)

    print(data)

Thus far, I have only been using load_data for datasets where both data_0 and data_1 have the same length of columns (same length of time-series). However, I am now encountering a situation where data_1 has a shorter column length than data_0; this is because the data in data_1 only starts getting recorded at some later time than data_0.
How do I use pandas to fill the columns of data_1 with leading zeros, such that the column length in both data_0 and data_1 is the same? I believe that the line data.fillna(0, inplace=True) is filling the length mismatch with trailing zeros; is there an obvious way to change this to leading zeros? Note that I do not know the length of either dataset a priori, so I would appreciate help towards a solution that works based on the length of the data loaded using pandas. Running the example above gives an output
   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  1  2  A  B
1  3  4  5  C  D
2  6  7  8  0  0

which is evidently not the desired effect (the zeros in columns d and e would be in row 0, rather than 2).
I have tried different options for DataFrame.fillna such as method=backfill, but none of these attempts have yielded the expected result.

Oh, are you not aware of merging? See Pandas Merging 101

This isn't actually a minimal working example because there's no example data (input, desired output, and actual output). You should also show how the function's being called. Or, if the CSV parsing is all working perfectly, just provide data_0 and data_1 themselves (example versions, that is). See How to make good reproducible pandas examples.

Apologies @wjandrea, I will add the required data to make it a minimal working example when I next get access to my computer.

Here's one approach:

Reverse row order of your dfs with [::-1] and apply df.reset_index with drop=True
Apply pd.concat on axis=1, and reverse + reset_index again
Finally, apply df.fillna

import pandas as pd
from io import StringIO

def load_data(filename):
    
    headers_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    headers_1 = ['d', 'e']

    # using StringIO for mre 
    # + `sep="\s+"` for `delim_whitespace=True` (deprecated since 2.2.0)
    data_0 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(c_0), header=None, sep="\s+")
    data_0.columns = headers_0[0:data_0.shape[1]]

    data_1 = pd.read_csv(StringIO(c_1), header=None, sep="\s+")
    data_1.columns = headers_1[0:data_1.shape[1]]

    data = (
        pd.concat(
            [df[::-1].reset_index(drop=True) for df in [data_0, data_1]], 
            axis=1
        )[::-1]
        .reset_index(drop=True)
        .fillna(0)
    )

    return data

c_0 = """0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8"""

c_1 = """A B
C D
"""

load_data('c')

   a  b  c  d  e
0  0  1  2  0  0
1  3  4  5  A  B
2  6  7  8  C  D

Will work regardless of which one is longer.

Another option could be to use df.shift with fill_value:
def load_data2(filename):
    
    # `data_0` and `data_1` same as above

    diff = len(data_0) - len(data_1)
    
    data = pd.concat([data_0, data_1], axis=1)
    if diff > 0:
        data[data_1.columns] = data[data_1.columns].shift(diff, fill_value=0)
    elif diff < 0:
        data[data_0.columns] = data[data_0.columns].shift(abs(diff), fill_value=0)
    
    return data

The nice thing about this option is that it will only fill NaN values in the shifted area. E.g.:
c_0 = """0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8"""

c_1 = """A B
C 
"""

load_data2('c')

   a  b  c  d    e
0  0  1  2  0    0
1  3  4  5  A    B
2  6  7  8  C  NaN # with my `load_data` above, this `NaN` gets filled too!

Of course, if you want all NaN values filled anyway, just use fillna here as well.

Thanks for the answer @ouroboros1 ! From your example of the code execution, it appears that this is adding zeros after the c_1 data, and not before it? I would expect the zeros in columns ‘d’ and ‘e’ to appear first?

Yes, my bad. Updated :)

Thank you! I have marked this as answered, given that your first solution is the most compact one, and requires the least number of if/then statements.

I don't really know much about pandas, I did manage to find a solution in my own way:
import pandas as pd
from pathlib import Path

def load_data(filename):
    headers_0 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    headers_1 = ['d', 'e']

    data_0 = pd.read_csv(str(filename.with_suffix('')) + '_0.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    data_0.columns = headers_0[0:data_0.shape[1]]

    data_1 = pd.read_csv(str(filename.with_suffix('')) + '_1.csv', header=None, delim_whitespace=True)
    data_1.columns = headers_1[0:data_1.shape[1]]

    len_0 = len(data_0)
    len_1 = len(data_1)

    if len_0 > len_1:
        zeros_to_prepend = pd.DataFrame(0, index=range(len_0 - len_1), columns=data_1.columns)
        data_1 = pd.concat([zeros_to_prepend, data_1], ignore_index=True)

    data = data_0.join(data_1)
    return data

filename = Path('filename/') # I didn't really understand what this was for, so just entered filename
data = load_data(filename)
print(data)

This was my output:
    a   b   c    d    e
0   1   2   3    0    0
1   4   5   6    0    0
2   7   8   9  100  200
3  10  11  12  300  400

There were also a few warnings when using pandas for me. It said that a keyword used in pandas was deprecated. I'm using linux though so it may be some issue on my end!

"a keyword used in pandas was deprecated" - Which one? delim_whitespace is in fact deprecated; you can check the docs.

@wjandrea Ooh ok. Thanks for the info. But wait did they change it sep='\s+' if i read it correctly. That's so unnecessarily complicated for no reason though.
